# Show button after login

Tags: php, css

i have a joomla login component,now i want when user successfully logs in to show a button that is hidden by css with display:none...here is how i tried...

```
<?php if (true === $app->login($credentials, $options)) {
        // Success

        $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', array());
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_($app->getUserState('users.login.form.return'), false));
        ?><script>
        $$('.formBtn').setStyles({
  display:box;
});
        </script>
        <?php



    } else {
        // Login failed !
        $data['remember'] = (int)$options['remember'];
        $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML markup look like?  In what way is the code not working?  Also, I hope you're not relying on CSS-based hiding as a security measure...

Comment: it doesnt show anything,the button is still hidden,i have an appointment button that is hidden and when user logs in it is supposed to be shown...why isnt that a good idea?

Comment: `"It doesn't show anything"` - Are you sure?  Look at the actual HTML, not just what's rendered in the display by CSS.  You're talking about client-side functionality, so you need to do a little debugging of the HTML/CSS/JavaScript to know what's going on.  As for why it's not a good idea, CSS isn't a security measure.  The button is still _there_, it's just not visible by default.  Anybody who wants to access it still can.  More importantly, you need to secure the functionality which the button _performs_, not just hide the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i did it eventually...

```
<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser();
if($user->id)
{
?>


<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
  $$('.formBtn').setStyle('display', 'block');
});


</script>
<?php
}
else
{
echo "NOT LOGGED!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several mistakes in your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(".formBtn").css("display", "box");</script>
```

And remember to use this **after** the button is already rendered.

Comment: im sorry im new at this,is this jquerys script and what do you mean after the button is already rendered?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's a jQuery script.
2. Make sure the button, you want to show, is already printed out or else the script will fail, meaning, there wont be a button to change the style for.